Keep the Stackview's content aspect ratio while limiting Stackview's height
I want to show a YouTube video cover (with an aspect ratio of 16:9) in the center of the top half of the screen with respect to the device's orientation. How can I achieve it in the Xcode storyboard?
what I have done so far:

added a Stack view and adjusted it in the top half of the safe area.
Set the alignment to center
Set the content mode to Aspect Fit
added a UIView to the stack view
set the aspect ratio

What I want:

What's the point of StackView? I'm trying to limit the height of the child view while keeping the aspect ratio using "Aspect Fit" content mode.

What is the point of the stack view? Delete it and just configure the UIView.

It sounds like you are only ever going to add one view into this stack view, in which case, you don't need a stack view at all.

edited the question.

What's the point of StackView? I'm trying to limit the height of the child view while keeping the aspect ratio using "Aspect Fit" content mode. (1) But you can limit the height of the "child view" and keep the aspect ratio without using a Stack View. (2) You seem to be the victim of a misconception here: "content mode" has to do with the drawing of an image in an image view, it does absolutely nothing when you're talking about the aspect ratio of a view's size.

No need for a stack view....
Let's create a UIView with a red background -this will be your video view (or a "holder" for it):
let v16x9 = UIView()
v16x9.backgroundColor = .red
    
v16x9.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(v16x9)

To cut down on typing, declare the safe area:
let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

Now the constraints:
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    // top to top of safe area
    v16x9.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
    // center horizontally
    v16x9.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
    // keep the width less-than-or-equal-to the safe area
    v16x9.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.widthAnchor),
    // view height is 16:9 ratio
    v16x9.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v16x9.widthAnchor, multiplier: 9.0 / 16.0),
    // keep height less-than-or-equal-to one-half (50%) of the safe area
    v16x9.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
])

// stretch the view as wide as possible, while respecting the other constraint restrictions
let wc: NSLayoutConstraint = v16x9.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor)
wc.priority = .defaultHigh
wc.isActive = true


Edit
To set this up in Storyboard, follow the comments as instructions.

Here's the source of that Storyboard:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="22154" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_12" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="22130"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="s0d-6b-0kx">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="Y6W-OH-hqX" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="5EZ-qb-Rvc">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="852"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="CLw-Ba-ZZk" userLabel="RedUIView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="59" width="393" height="221"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemRedColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="CLw-Ba-ZZk" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="16:9" id="D78-kc-JCT"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vDu-zF-Fre"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="CLw-Ba-ZZk" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="width" priority="750" id="AN4-IG-kQf"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="CLw-Ba-ZZk" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="5EZ-qb-Rvc" secondAttribute="centerX" id="NHW-cs-7a0"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="CLw-Ba-ZZk" firstAttribute="width" relation="lessThanOrEqual" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="width" id="PNx-hV-q3d"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="CLw-Ba-ZZk" firstAttribute="height" relation="lessThanOrEqual" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="0.5" id="mbh-I7-eel"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="CLw-Ba-ZZk" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="top" id="rfH-ZU-ocg"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Ief-a0-LHa" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-21" y="5"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemRedColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.23137254901960785" blue="0.18823529411764706" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>


Would you show me in Storyboard?

@ZahraJamshidi - see the Edit to my answer.
